# Suspending the current ssh connection

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, ssh

I'm new to Ubuntu and trying to learn ssh connections. I learned trick to suspend the current SSH connection and come back to localhost using:

<kbd>~</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>

When I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>, I suppose that the <kbd>~</kbd> shouldn't be visible until I press <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>(which makes my ssh connection to be suspended and come back to `localhost`).

However at times it works as expected i.e <kbd>~</kbd> is not visible until I press <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>. But at times <kbd>~</kbd> is been visible at terminal once I press the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> keys, which makes the suspending ssh impossible!

Am I missing something here.

Thanks in advance.